# Run iOS and Android Apps on XUbuntu Jammy?

Tags: xubuntu, android, emulation, ios

I want to use iOS and Android apps on XUbuntu Jammy.
No, not games. There are apps I need that only have Android or iOS versions of them, nothing for any PC of any kind.

I know about Nox and Bluestacks for Windows, just don't know anything about anything for Xubuntu.

Searched these forums, checked all possible keywords, including Virtual Machine suggestion, eventually ended up with search results that took me places with no clear answer.

'Emulator', 'Virtualization', these are the words that keep popping up.

I am no Techie.

All I know is my PC can carry a baby PC (the throttled, bottled things that are our so-called 'smart' phones) on its system, much like a Mother Ship carrying fighter jets.

So, do I go and download the software on my 'phone', or hope for a nice and useful answer here?

If I can get an answer here, that would mean being able to use my phone on my PC.
Literally.

Would be so cool.

Many thanks in advance.

I am open to:
'Look up...'
'Try...'

With links leading to clear instructions for tech dummies like me.

Appreciated.

Gupse

Comment: Apple's not going to allow any iOS emulators to exist

Comment: My brain's logic department was sending a similar message as I wrote, but I was still hoping.
Would be nice to liberate our apps from their encasements.